# GCC compiler flags different between native and haswell

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, gcc4.9

I am on a linux haswell box but when doing

```
gcc -march=native -Q --help=target
```

it has different compiler switches than doing

```
gcc -march=haswell -Q --help=target
```

I typed the following to see the differences side by side

```
diff -u <(gcc -march=native -Q --help=target) <(gcc -march=haswell -Q --help=target) | grep "^[-|+] "
```

Is there something misconfigured for the haswell architecture type that needs to be set up for the compiler in this case?

That diff command above shows the following flag differences.

```
-  -mabm                                [enabled]
+  -mabm                                [disabled]
-  -maes                                [enabled]
+  -maes                                [disabled]
-  -mavx                                [enabled]
-  -mavx2                               [enabled]
+  -mavx                                [disabled]
+  -mavx2                               [disabled]
-  -mbmi                                [enabled]
-  -mbmi2                               [enabled]
+  -mbmi                                [disabled]
+  -mbmi2                               [disabled]
-  -mcx16                               [enabled]
+  -mcx16                               [disabled]
-  -mf16c                               [enabled]
+  -mf16c                               [disabled]
-  -mfma                                [enabled]
+  -mfma                                [disabled]
-  -mfsgsbase                           [enabled]
+  -mfsgsbase                           [disabled]
-  -mfxsr                               [enabled]
+  -mfxsr                               [disabled]
-  -mlzcnt                              [enabled]
+  -mlzcnt                              [disabled]
-  -mmmx                                [enabled]
-  -mmovbe                              [enabled]
+  -mmmx                                [disabled]
+  -mmovbe                              [disabled]
-  -mno-sse4                            [disabled]
+  -mno-sse4                            [enabled]
-  -mpclmul                             [enabled]
-  -mpopcnt                             [enabled]
+  -mpclmul                             [disabled]
+  -mpopcnt                             [disabled]
-  -mrdrnd                              [enabled]
+  -mrdrnd                              [disabled]
-  -msahf                               [enabled]
+  -msahf                               [disabled]
-  -msse                                [enabled]
-  -msse2                               [enabled]
+  -msse                                [disabled]
+  -msse2                               [disabled]
-  -msse3                               [enabled]
-  -msse4                               [enabled]
-  -msse4.1                             [enabled]
-  -msse4.2                             [enabled]
+  -msse3                               [disabled]
+  -msse4                               [disabled]
+  -msse4.1                             [disabled]
+  -msse4.2                             [disabled]
-  -mssse3                              [enabled]
+  -mssse3                              [disabled]
-  -mtune=                              haswell
+  -mtune=
-  -mxsave                              [enabled]
-  -mxsaveopt                           [enabled]
+  -mxsave                              [disabled]
+  -mxsaveopt                           [disabled]
```

Comment: Before gcc version 6, the way the options are reported is confusing. Of course SSE2 is not disabled...